# Are groups of order $p(p + 1)$ solvable nilpotent?

Tags: abstract-algebra, nilpotence, solvable-groups

> Are groups of order $p(p + 1)$ solvable nilpotent?

I proved before that groups of order $p(p + 1)$ have a normal subgroup of order $p$ or a normal subgroup of order $p + 1$.

In that case if we have normal subgroup $H$ of order $p + 1$, then $G$ is nilpotent since the series $1 \lhd H \lhd G$ and the factors are abelian. However, what about solvability and nilpotent in the other cases ?

Comment: Abelian factors = solvable, which is less than nilpotent. Consider the symmetric group $S_3$ of order $2(2+1)$. It has a normal subgroup of order $2+1$, but is not nilpotent.

Comment: Furthermore, a group of order $p+1$ is not necessarily solvable let alone abelian. Consider the case $p=59$. We can have $G=C_{59}\times A_5$, which is not solvable because $A_5$ isn't.

Comment: What you have proved does show that a group of order $p(p+1)$ cannot be *simple*.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen By factors I mean their quotient. $G/H = Z_p$ so it is abelian.

Comment: Of course, so do I. But why would that matter to anything I said in the above comments?

Comment: Yeah I see. I understand your comment. I was wondering do we know that subgroups of order $p(p + 1)$ is atleast solvable. I mean from your comment we know it is not nilpotent.

Comment: The second example shows that it is not necessarily solvable either. The thing staring at your face is that $p+1$ is very uncontrolled as an order of a group, because it can have a lot prime factors, and we can take advantage. $p=59$ is just a case in point.

Comment: I was wondering how did you get $G = C_{59} \times A_5$ ?

Comment: I picked the smallest non-solvable group I could think of. That is $A_5$ of order $60$. Hey, $60=p+1$ for the prime $p=59$, let's try and use that!